# How to run loading animation on load website?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, jquery-animate, loading

I create this [website](http://hmahdavi.zgig.ir/%D9%86%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87%20%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B101/Index.html) by this [template](http://demo.themeregion.com/butex/). In this website must when load site display loading . But when loading my website get error :

> Could not load the image

I sew the main.js file and found that  this code run this message.I debug this codes in ff debugger but  don't solved.

Jquery codes :

```
// Preloader function
var cSpeed = 7;
var cWidth = 75;
var cHeight = 75;
var cTotalFrames = 8;
var cFrameWidth = 75;
var cImageSrc = '/images/sprites.gif';

var cImageTimeout = false;

function startAnimation() {

    document.getElementById('loaderImage').innerHTML = '<canvas id="canvas" width="' + cWidth + '" height="' + cHeight + '"><p>Your browser does not support the canvas element.</p></canvas>';

    //FPS = Math.round(100/(maxSpeed+2-speed));
    FPS = Math.round(100 / cSpeed);
    SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 1 / FPS;
    g_GameObjectManager = null;
    g_run = genImage;

    g_run.width = cTotalFrames * cFrameWidth;
    genImage.onload = function () { cImageTimeout = setTimeout(fun, 0) };
    initCanvas();
}


function imageLoader(s, fun)//Pre-loads the sprites image
{
    clearTimeout(cImageTimeout);
    cImageTimeout = 0;
    genImage = new Image();
    genImage.onload = function () { cImageTimeout = setTimeout(fun, 0) };
    genImage.onerror = new Function('alert(\'Could not load the image\')');
    genImage.src = s;
}

//The following code starts the animation
new imageLoader(cImageSrc, 'startAnimation()');
```

I try to save this gif image but I can not do this right.I don't have sprites.gif image in my website . How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The sprites.gif file is here [sprites.gif](http://demo.themeregion.com/butex/images/sprites.gif)

Download it and upload it to your "/images" directory. Basically you are missing that file and when the plugin tries to reach it a 302 redirection occurs to a 404 page. See it yourself: [Page redirection because of missing file](http://hmahdavi.zgig.ir/%D9%86%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87%20%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B101/images/sprites.gif)

Comment: Ricardo Campos : Thank you  for your answering . I do this but get error.

Comment: I solve this . I change in jquery code this line (var cImageSrc = 'images/sprites.gif';) and solved

Comment: I can see the files in that directory and I cannot see "sprites.gif". Here is the list of [files](http://hmahdavi.zgig.ir/%D9%86%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87%20%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B101/images/). Do you see sprites.gif there?